# Removing ImageView Space if it not exits in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am new in IOS. I am displaying a image from server. Now If image is exits, then it is displaying to me . Now I am trying that if image is not exits then ImageView Space should be remove. I am displaying to image in TableView.

```
 // display the posted Image. currently we are displaying only one image if there exits.
NSString *myString=@"";
if(wall.imageNames.count != 0){
    tempCell.imageViewPostedImage.hidden = NO;

    myString = [wall.imageNames objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *imageGlary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@",wall.imagePath, ImageSize400, myString];

    NSLog(@"imageGlary %@",imageGlary);

    [[[CustomNetwork alloc] init] setImage:imageGlary onImageView:tempCell.imageViewPostedImage withPlaceHolderImage:DefaultImage65];
} else {


    tempCell.imageViewPostedImage.hidden = YES; }
```

This is my code But it is hidding to imageView not removing the space.

Comment: are you asking about lazy loading

Comment: I want to remove the ImageView space. so that my bottom view will be at the place of imageview if image is not exits.

Comment: I want to move the bottom view to up at replace of imageview. So i am trying to remove the space of imageview

Comment: if(wall.imageNames.count != 0) it will tell us that we haven't image. so i think, we dont need to customNetwork code

Comment: @RahulRawat are you using autolayout? and images are local or not?

Comment: @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani- -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath                  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GolferWallCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: I created custom cell, and put imageview with Labels and Buttons. I am new here and haven't too much know

Comment: then you have to change frame of your cell's subviews and set row height using `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate.

Comment: Great. I am also thinking it. But new in IOS may you please give me some examples ?

Comment: I just did in heightForRowAtIndexPath. But text are overlapping with another row's text.

Comment: I fixed it by **CGRectMake(5, 100, 310, 30);** and change the height of row dynamically. Thank you ** Chinttu**

Comment: @RahulRawat : If solved your issue with my answer please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Create frame only if image exists, in,

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

then,  check the same in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and set the cell height separate for both cells.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```